# Running UWP application from ASP.NET web application

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, uwp

I have developed a UWP application and now I want to run that from another ASP.NET MVC application. Is there anyway to do this?
I know this can't be done by `Process` class because UWP applications don't have a standalone `.exe` output.
Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching in Microsoft Documents, I found the following article:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xbox-apps/automate-launching-uwp-apps

> **Launch activation**
>
> You can also launch the app by using launch
>   activation. No setup is required, but the Application User Model ID
>   (AUMID) of the UWP app is needed. The AUMID is the package family name
>   followed by an exclamation point and the application ID. The best way
>   to obtain the package family name is to complete these steps:
>
> 1. Open the Package.appxmanifest file.
> 2. On the Packaging tab, enter the Package name.
> 3. If the Package family name is not listed, open
>      PowerShell and run `>get-appxpackage MyPackageName` to find the
>      PackageFamilyName.
>
> The application ID can be found in the
>   Package.appxmanifest file (opened in XML view) under the
>   `<Applications>` element.
>
> **Command line**
>
> A tool for performing a launch activation of a UWP app is installed
>   with the Windows 10 SDK. It can be run from the command line, and it
>   takes the AUMID of the app to be launched as an argument.
>
> `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\App Certification Kit\microsoft.windows.softwarelogo.appxlauncher.exe <AUMID>`
>
> It would look something like this:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\App Certification Kit\microsoft.windows.softwarelogo.appxlauncher.exe" MyPackageName_ph1m9x8skttmg!AppId
```

First I tried to use Protocol activation, but it failed with no apparent reason, so I took a shot at Launch activation and it worked for me. Assuming that you have the UWP application source such as in my case, after retrieving Application User Model ID, all you should do is to create a `Process` object and start it from your code like this:

```
            var runApp = new Process
            {
                StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
                {
                    FileName = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\App Certification Kit\microsoft.windows.softwarelogo.appxlauncher.exe",
                    Arguments = "MyPackageName_ph1m9x8skttmg!AppId"
                }
            };
            runApp.Start();
```

**It works in ASP.NET** as well with no problem.